Redirect to supported language directory if no language have been selected with .htaccess, but keeping the subpath
Basically what I need is:
if the user types
www.mydomain.com
htaccess checks what is the user language. If it is 'en' or 'pt-br', it redirects to
www.mydomain.com/en/ (english)
or
www.mydomain.com/pt-br/ (brazilian portuguese)
These are the two supported languages. But, if the user types, for example:
www.mydomain.com/any-existing-subpath
htacces redirects to
www.mydomain.com/en/any-existing-subpath
or
www.mydomain.com/pt-br/any-existing-subpath
Depending on the user language  (if it is one of the supported languages)
But, if the user language is none of supported languages, the default language should be 'en'.
I have tryed this, but this way the user language is not taking in account.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(?!en/|pt-br/)(.*) /en/$1 [L,R=301]

Thanks!

"/any-existing-subpath" - How do you determine whether it is an "existing subpath" or not? Do you mean a physical filesystem directory perhaps? Or an arbitrary URL in your application (as stored in your "database")?

The existing subpaths are those defined in the router. But this does not affect the issue. In fact, the idea is to always add the language (for example /en or /pt-br) when the user types a url, if he has not already typed the language.
